# MVVM Light - There is already a factory registered for INavigationService

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm-light

I have Xamarin Forms application with MVVM Light. I created NavigationService class and registered it in the constructor:

```
public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Setup navigation service:
        var navigationService = new NavigationService();
        // Configure pages:
        navigationService.Configure(AppPages.MainPage, typeof(MainPage));
        navigationService.Configure(AppPages.DetailsPage, typeof(DetailsPage));
        // Register NavigationService in IoC container:
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<INavigationService>(() => navigationService);

        // Create new Navigation Page and set MainPage as its default page:
        var firstPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
        // Set Navigation page as default page for Navigation Service:
        navigationService.Initialize(firstPage);
        // You have to also set MainPage property for the app:
        MainPage = firstPage;
    }
```

Once I exit the app with back arrow on Android and reopen it I have exception:

[image]

I tried different approaches: unregistering and registering service again or checking if service is already registered but there are still some issues. I would be grateful for help.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like below - it is working now correctly:

```
public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        INavigationService navigationService;

        if (!SimpleIoc.Default.IsRegistered<INavigationService>())
        {
            // Setup navigation service:
            navigationService = new NavigationService();

            // Configure pages:
            navigationService.Configure(AppPages.MainPage, typeof(MainPage));
            navigationService.Configure(AppPages.DetailsPage, typeof(DetailsPage));

            // Register NavigationService in IoC container:
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<INavigationService>(() => navigationService);
        }

        else
            navigationService = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<INavigationService>();

        // Create new Navigation Page and set MainPage as its default page:
        var firstPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
        // Set Navigation page as default page for Navigation Service:
        navigationService.Initialize(firstPage);
        // You have to also set MainPage property for the app:
        MainPage = firstPage;
    }
```

Remember to add below methods to INavigationService interface:

```
void Configure(AppPages pageKey, Type pageType);
void Initialize(NavigationPage page);
```